# mvc 5 site trace monitoring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, trace

I have mvc 5 site and I use Trace.WriteLine(). Something like that

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("It is testing trace string");
   return View();
}
```

I need write C# Console application which will read those Trace messages in real time. So it will allow me monotoring site activity. Few questions here:

1) It is good practise use Trace messages for monitoring activity or there are some better ways?

2) When site write Trace.WriteLine() where that data stored? Some memory object?

3) How I can make C# tool which get trace messages only from that site?

Comment: Do you know the trace.axd page? It monitors all page requests to your site. You need to add to the web.config, inside system.web
<trace pageOutput="false" enabled="true" />

Comment: You can also monitor these messages with DebugView http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx although I don't know how well it would work (if at all with a web app, and you  would have to do it on the server). The best answer is what Paulo suggested. trace.axd

Comment: trace.axd? Sure. It is working, but it generate too much details and I cant store it somewhere. Also for some reason it doesnt show actually the message I save to like "It is testing trace string". http://gyazo.com/f75e20cf8035de1b4919845f4c308d23 So i need something more advanced here.

Comment: Mike, DebugView doesnt work for mvc5 site even If I run it localy.